# How to test the page behind authentication in lighthouse report using gulp task?

Tags: gulp, lighthouse

I am automating the lighthouse report in chrome browser.
But the URL I want to test is behind the authentication. so when I run the task it generates the lighthouse report for authentication page. How can I test the actual URL?

```
gulp.task("lighthouse", function () {
    return launchChromeAndRunLighthouse('http://localhost:8080/Template/GetTemplate?templateName=IndexDev', flags).then(results => {
        //  console.log(results);
        write(results, 'html', 'report.html')

    });
});

function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(url, flags) {
    return chromeLauncher.launch().then(chrome => {
        flags.port = chrome.port;
        return lighthouse(url, flags).then();
    });
}
```